# Does generalized Parseval identity series: $\langle g,h\rangle =\sum_{1}^{\infty}\langle g,e_i\rangle\langle e_i,h\rangle$ absolutely converge

Tags: functional-analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, parsevals-identity

The generalized Parseval identity states that given $\{e_i\}_1^\infty$ a complete orthonormal system in Hilbert space $H$ then for all $g,h\in H : \langle g,h\rangle =\sum_{i=1}^{i=\infty} \langle g,e_i \rangle \langle e_i , h \rangle$. I don't know if it is true, yet I try to show that the series absolutely converges, i.e $\sum_1^\infty |\langle g,e_i\rangle||\langle e_i,h\rangle| <\infty $.

The only thing  I had in mind for bounding $\sum_1^\infty |\langle g,e_i\rangle||\langle e_i,h\rangle|$ is Cauchy Schwartz inequality , i.e $\sum_1^\infty |\langle g,e_i\rangle||\langle e_i,h\rangle| \le \sum_1^\infty ||g||\cdot||e_i||\cdot||e_i|| \cdot||h|| = \sum_1^\infty ||g|| \cdot ||h||$ , but it seems as if this is too curse bound since this sum doesn't generally converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $n \in \Bbb{N}$, and consider the vectors
\begin{align*}
u &= (|\langle g, e_1 \rangle|, \ldots, |\langle g, e_n \rangle|), \\
v &= (|\langle e_1, h \rangle|, \ldots, |\langle e_n, h \rangle|).
\end{align*}
Then, by Cauchy-Schwarz on $\Bbb{R}^n$,
$$u \cdot v \le \|u\| \|v\| \implies \sum_{i=1}^n |\langle g, e_i \rangle| |\langle e_i, h \rangle| \le \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |\langle g, e_i \rangle|^2} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |\langle e_i, h \rangle|^2}.$$
Given that the $e_i$s are orthonormal, we have
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |\langle g, e_i \rangle|^2} &\le \|g\| \\
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |\langle e_i, h \rangle|^2} &\le \|h\|,
\end{align*}
hence
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |\langle g, e_i \rangle| |\langle e_i, h \rangle| \le \|g\| \|h\| < \infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

What you want is almost the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. In general, the Hölder inequality tells you that if $1/p+1/q=1,$ then 
for any $f_1,f_2:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{C},$ we have $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |f_1(j)f_2(j)|\leq (\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |f_1(j)|^p)^{1/p}(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|f_2(j)|^q)^{1/q}$. In your case, we have $p=q=2$ and the right hand side would be $||g||_2^2||h||_2^2$ by Parseval. This yields absolute convergence.